# Determining if time is full or half hour

Tags: java, date, datetime

I am setting up a date instance like this:

```
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
date.set(2015, 9, 25, 12, 0);
```

In this case, I know that it's `12:00`, a full hour, but I also have cases where I input the date parameters dynamically, so I want to determine if that date is a full or half hour.

E.g., for `12:00` and `12:30` it would return `true`, while for `12:23` it would return false.

I've tried `timeInMillis % 36000000` from another answer, but it didn't work.

Comment: Check if the minutes are 30 or 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use get minutes to check the minutes.

```
int minutes = date.get(Calendar.MINUTE); // gets the minutes
return (minutes == 0 || minutes == 30);
```

Comment: Thanks to @biziclop for pointing this first in the comments, and thanks to you for giving the actual code!

Comment: @AmarSyla: My answer had minutes from the get-go, just for the record. :-) I think I'd use this `||` rather than `%` if it were me, though, I just thought for some reason you were wanting to use `%`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I really wish I could select more then one correct answer. I am not an experienced programmer, and your method may be better than this one, but this looks cleaner. Thanks both of you.

Comment: @AmarSyla: Sorry, I may have been unclear above: I, also, would opt for this approach over using `%` as in my answer. :-) I was just flagging up that biziclop didn't bring up minutes "first." (Pride, phah.)

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track, you've just used the wrong value. With milliseconds, it would be 1800000. (But see [biziclop's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33335447/determining-if-time-is-full-or-half-hour/33335490#comment54467654_33335490) suggesting that's not a good idea.) I'd get the minutes and use `% 30 == 0`.

Gratuitous minutes example: ([live copy](http://ideone.com/VeMuhE))

```
for (int n = 0; n < 60; ++n) {
    System.out.println(n + ( n % 30 == 0 ? " <= Yes" : ""));
}
```

<s>Or in milliseconds: ([live copy](http://ideone.com/McWnjV))</s>

```
for (int n = 0; n < 3600000; n += 60000) {
    System.out.println(n + ( n % 1800000 == 0 ? " <= Yes" : ""));
}
```

Comment: There are two subtle differences between the two: if you count milliseconds since epoch, you won't have accounted for any leap seconds that might have been inserted in the calendar since 1970. While that's unlikely to make a difference in practice for many years to come, another, rather more pertinent difference is that calendars are localised and since some time zones do not use a multiple of 30 minutes as their time offset from UTC, you might get a very different result.

Comment: @biziclop: Thanks, very useful. So the take-away there is: Use my first example (minutes). :-)

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve. But it's good to be aware of the oddities of our timekeeping, particularly for someone like OP who is into developing mobile software, which could genuinely be used in places like Nepal (UTC +5:45).

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

You can let Java do the work for you. Use the java.time framework to query the date-time value for the minutes, seconds, and fraction-of-second.

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now ( ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" ) );
// If the value has any seconds or fraction of a second, we know this is neither full hour nor half hour.
if ( ( now.getSecond () != 0 ) || ( now.getNano () != 0 ) ) {
    System.out.println ( "now: " + now + " is neither full nor half hour, because of seconds or fraction-of-second." );
    return;
}
int minuteOfHour = now.getMinute ();
switch ( minuteOfHour ) {
    case 0:
        System.out.println ( "now: " + now + " is full hour." );
        break;
    case 30:
        System.out.println ( "now: " + now + " is half hour." );
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println ( "now: " + now + " is neither full nor half hour." );
        break;
}
```

The java.util.Date/.Calendar classes bundled with the early versions of Java are notoriously troublesome, and should be avoided. The java.time framework supplants them.